# rails whenver gem , running a command only if certain condition passes.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

We are using whenever gem with rails on our project. I understand that we can schedule a command using whenever gem like this.

```
every 1.day, :at => '6:00 am' do
  command "echo 'hello'"
end
```

but my problem is that i want to execute this command only when some condition is met. something like this.

```
every 1.day, :at => '6:00 am' do
 if User.any_new_user? 
  command "echo 'hello'"
 end
end
```

how can we achieve this with the whenever and rails?
One possible solution i can think of is that i create a runner for this and check that condition there.Something like:

```
every 1.day, :at => '6:00 am' do
  runner "User.say_conditional_hello"
end
```

and inside my user model:

```
def self.say_conditional_hello
    `echo "Hello"`
end
```

Any suggestions on this approach or any new approach will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to **only** schedule the task if the condition is true then I don't think its possible you can schedule a task then when its time for running the task, the code can decide if it should be run or not, depending on your conditions

> One possible solution i can think of is that i create a runner for this and check that condition there.Something like:

Yes this is one way of handeling this, however IMO the best behavior when using whenever is creating a rake task that checks for conditions then executes your code *or perform your job*

Something like:

#### Rake Task

```
namespace :user do
  desc "description"
  task check_for_new: :environment do
    if User.any_new_user? 
      # code
    end
  end
end
```

#### in your `schedule.rb` file

```
every 1.day, :at => '6:00 am' do
  rake "user:check_for_new"
end
```